# "Meanest Superhero" -- who was being discussed?

Tags: character-identification

I recall long ago a video or even television show that discussed a superhero who was either a contemporary of early Superman or predated him. I believe he was in 1930s or 40s serials.

What was interesting is that he was described as the "meanest" of superheroes. I think they show him using a criminal's head as a battering ram to open a door. No code like Superman or Batman, more like cops sadly were in those days, not infrequently using physical coercion to get confessions or just beat a suspect for exercise.

IIRC, the character did have a sort of costume which may have had a cape or not. He was a pretty big guy, like may have been an athlete before he started acting. I just want to know who this mean superhero was.

Comment: The Shadow perhaps ?

Comment: @Paulie_D: I don't know much of Shadow but I think I would remember that. Moreover, this guy had no subtlety, just punch and manhandle foes was his approach whereas was not The Shadow into mind control? Different use of crim's head than battering ram.

Comment: Wonder Wart-Hog is a mean one, but too late to be the answer to your question.

Comment: There are some similarities to *Gladiator*, but that was a novel.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladiator_(novel)

Comment: @Buzz: I saw the actual footage I refer to. Looked very much quality and stylistically like the original superman.

Comment: So you are looking for a film?  Was it live action or a cartoon?

Comment: @buzz: footage could have come from superman live-action tv show with George R.